# Swift 3 Login Function

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to write a login function in swift that sends and HTTP POST request to a webpage and then receives a JSON object in response. That part I got working perfectly; although, I am a bit confused with my code. Parts of it I got from online tutorials and I do not completely understand it. What I want to do is trigger a segue to another view when the login was successful. Also, when the login failed, I want to display a UILabel that says "Username and password don't match". Can someone help explain the code I have written and let me know how I can better implement it? Thank you.

ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var _username: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var _password: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var _button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var errorText: UILabel!

@IBAction func loginButtonPress(_ sender: Any) {
    let username = _username.text
    let password = _password.text

    if(username == "" || password == "") {
        return
    }

    DoLogin(username: username!, password: password!)
}
```

DoLogin Function:

```
func DoLogin(username: String, password: String) {
    let myUrl = URL(string: "http://MYURL.com");
    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string
    let postString = "username=\(username)&password=\(password)";
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

        if error != nil
        {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        // Print out response object
        print("response = \(response)")

        //Convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            if let parseJSON = json {
                // Access value of username, name, and email by its key
                let usernameValue = parseJSON["username"] as? String
                let nameValue = parseJSON["name"] as? String
                let emailValue = parseJSON["email"] as? String
                print("usernameValue: \(usernameValue)")
                print("nameValue: \(nameValue)")
                print("emailValue: \(emailValue)")
                if(usernameValue != nil && nameValue != nil && emailValue != nil) {
                    //The Login WAS SUCCESSFUL
                    //This is where I want to perform a segue to another view (like this)
                    //performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginToMain", sender: self) //This does not work
                    //Error above is (implicit use of 'self' in closuer; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit
                }
            } else {
                //Username and Password do not match
                print("Username and password do not match. Please Try again");
                //This is what I want to do
                self.errorText.isHidden = false
                //But nothing happens to the errorText UILabel

            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of performSegue put self.performSegue

And add a DispatchQueue wrapper to both of these

```
DispatchQueue.main.async
{
  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginToMain", sender: self)
}
```

..

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
     self.errorText.isHidden = false
}
```

When you are calling URLSession the code in its completion handler is running in a background thread, but GUI must be updated in the main thread. Adding DispatchQueue.main.async updates these in the main thread.

Comment: That worked PERFECTLY! Thank you very much for the help. I have never heard of DispatchQueue.

Answer (score 0):

"Grundwald eats a coelacanth" offered the answer to your immediate question and did a great job of instructing how to avoid the unwanted crash which came about from trying to perform a UI task on a background thread (in the completion handler of your URLRequest data task). You did ask another question, however, asking to explain a bit about what your code is actually doing. As much as I would suggest you avoid writing code you don't understand, of course there is no way to understand without an explanation (or lots of practice). As such, I'll write up a short explanation of what is going on logically in your code, and perform a few different actions in there which I think improve the readability of your code and/or increase standardization.

```
func doLogin(username: String, password: String) {
    let myUrl: URL? = URL(string: "http://MYURL.com") // instantiate a URL object (this is failable, so type is Optional)
    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!) // instantiate a URLRequest by implicitly unwrapping the URL (asserting it isn't nil)
    request.httpMethod = "POST" // perform the http request using the POST verb
    let postString = "username=\(username)&password=\(password)" // create a list of query parameters (not actually JSON)
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) // encode the string as UTF8 and assign httpBody with a Data type object

    // now create a data task object, but don't do anything with it yet; just define it
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        guard error == nil else { // if there is an error, print it and return
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        // convert http response to a standard Swift dictionary of type [String:Any] (aka Dictionary<String, Any>)
        // since you aren't handling the potential for an error from this `try` anyway, I've converted it to a `try?`
        // this does away with the `do`/`catch` blocks and makes things a bit less verbose
        let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)

        guard let parseJSON = json as? [String:Any] else { // confirm that our serialization and cast to [String:Any] didn't produce nil, otherwise:
            print("Serializing JSON object failed") // note: this has nothing to do with the names matching (as you suggested before)
            self.errorText.isHidden = false // this probably doesn't do anything considering we never set `isHidden` as true in the first place
            return
        }

        // make sure we received all of the parameters we expected (though you don't use these, so not sure that you need it)
        guard let usernameValue = parseJSON["username"] as? String,
            let _ = parseJSON["name"] as? String,
            let _ = parseJSON["email"] as? String else {
                print("Did not receive all return parameters")
                return
        }

        guard usernameValue == username else { // if our usernames don't match, there was some kind of problem?
            print("Usernames did not match")
            return
        }

        // if we haven't failed anything before this, then we're in the clear; go ahead and segue
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            // we perform this in the `main` queue since it is a UI task and cannot be executed in a background queue
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginToMain", sender: self)
        })
    }
    task.resume() // start the actual URLRequest data task; before this line, none of the above code has been executed yet
}
```

Without all the comments, and excluding some of the (in my opinion) unnecessary sections, the function now looks like this:

```
func doLogin(username: String, password: String) {
    let myUrl: URL? = URL(string: "http://MYURL.com")
    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "username=\(username)&password=\(password)"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        guard error == nil else { return }

        let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)
        guard let parseJSON = json as? [String:Any] else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                self.errorText.isHidden = false
            })
            return
        }

        guard let usernameValue = parseJSON["username"] as? String,
            usernameValue == username else {
                print("Usernames did not match")
                return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginToMain", sender: self)
        })
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Of course this misses a few important steps. If I were you, I would change this up a bit to perhaps take a completion handler and/or an error handler. Since it is performed asynchronously, this kind of method is quite common for getting the desired result.

```
enum APIError: Error {
    case parseError(String)
    case usernameMismatch(String)
}

func doLogin(username: String, password: String, onCompletion: (() -> Void)? = nil, onError: ((Error?) -> Void)? = nil) {
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://MYURL.com")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = "username=\(username)&password=\(password)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        do {
            guard error == nil else {
                onError?(error)
                return
            }

            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)
            guard let parseJSON = json as? [String:Any] else {
                onError?(APIError.parseError("Cannot parse JSON result!"))
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                    self.errorText.isHidden = false
                })
                return
            }

            guard let usernameValue = parseJSON["username"] as? String,
                usernameValue == username else {
                    onError?(APIError.usernameMismatch("Usernames do not match!"))
                    return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginToMain", sender: self)
                onCompletion?()
            })
        } catch let error {
            onError?(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Hopefully this helps in answering the other part of your question. Let me know if there is anything I can clarify.